# Why isn't the constructor setting a parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, field

I'm narrowing in on completion of a specialized data parsing and management class and have run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I have an activity class named `RecordDisposal` and a data class named `DisposalRecord` (sorry for the poor naming; I couldn't come up with anything else that wouldn't confuse the matter with other things).

So I set up some basic tests, and things aren't really working out (see image).  At the breakpoint, the field `UnparsedRetentionCode` should have been set to the parameter value `RetentionCode` (see line above the breakpoint), which in this case is `1`, but it's not (see Locals window at the bottom).

What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please dont use images of code in posts.  Post the actual code and the full error you're receiving.

Comment: I'd agree that he should have put his code in text but the image of the locals debug window was useful.

Comment: also you may want to read up and or brush up on how to set Properties also look at how to implement Auto Properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UnparsedRetentionCode is null in the watch window because your setter is effectively performing `_fullRetentionCode = _fullRetentionCode` (which upon object creation is null).

It should be:

```
private set
{
    _fullRetentionCode = value;
}
```

[MSDN reference on c# properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your setter is setting the backing field; to the value of the backing field (via the property getter). So its always null.

Instead:

```
public string UnparsedRetentionCode
{
    get { return _fullRetentionCode; }
    private set { _fullRetentionCode = value; }
}
```

So the assignment actually works;